# Incorrect lit shadows (shadows too bright and there should be no light)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles, lighting, shadows

I have a problem with flora shadows on one exact scene layer. Top image is older version and bottom is newer. As you can see on top image there are correct shadows with no light on trees and the shadows are dark as they should be. On the bottom picture the result is way worse because there shouldnt be any light on trees behind the mountains on the left and shadows are very well lit as they shouldnt be.

I took a long break between these 2 versions, so i dont remember if I changed anything about trees or something else. But the render settings are the same.

Any ideas why is it like that?

p.s. Its not because of the new fog - fog is on different layer, so its doesnt affect the forest layer. And composite settings are also the same.

[image: Older version with good flora shadows]
[image: Newer version with bad flora shadows]

The link to download 2 versions of project state: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wQfnNcYoFP2gBMD4BrVUvE_G3G4PCsjO?usp=sharing
Please do not modify or redistribute these files.

Comment: what are the 2 versions? I wonder if there is not a difference in light calculation between 2.7 and 2.8 (and next versions)

Comment: I mean 2 versions of my project, not of Blender. Its Blender 3.0 which I used for whole time of this project.

Comment: maybe it has to do with the world? but it would affect the rest of the image... or a hidden light?

Comment: There seems to be some shadow at least. Only not as dark as in your previous version. Did you make any changes on that layer?
Can you provide your blend file?

Comment: It feels like the light is kinda leaking through the mountains, there should be no light at all. I wonder if it can be the trees, maybe i made it more translucent then it was before?
I didnt change anything on that layer as i remember. I compared almost everything in both of the .blend files and dont see the reason why it happened.

Comment: There's a car in the second image that has a very well lit roof. Do you remember if you did anything to the lighting to compensate for the addition of the car? Another option is to try changing the Color Management View Transform (maybe you went back and forth between filmic and standard?).

Comment: @ChristopherBennett i didnt do anything to lighting. Yeah, i also thought about it and checked - Both scenes you the same filmic view transform

Comment: Please provide your blend file otherwise it's only guesswork

Comment: @Timmethy I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me both of them render as they should:

[image]

I just changed the noise threshold to 0.1 and the resolution to 50% to reduce rendertime.

Tested on windows 11 with Blender 3.1.2

Comment: Hmm, quite strange. I will try to render it out on my second PC and let you know if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: You can also try and render only the layer the trees are on to exclude compositing from causing the issue

Comment: Nope, it also renders it out with light out of nowhere on my second PC: [link](https://ibb.co/JW1c1z7)
Any chance we can contact on discord and find out why it's like that? Maybe i'll also pay you for rendering it out for me in full resolution?
And yes, i also did try to render it out without compositing - no sucess

Comment: Oh, i guess its the Blender 3.0 version issue, because i just tested it on 3.1.2 and everything lit right. Thank you, Timmethy.